# Filter sections out when running bin/buildout?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython, buildout

I have just reported [this issue upstream to IPython](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10420) but I believe that a workaround might exist in Buildout if I can filter out that section altogether.

#### Travis Builds

On Travis, the same code builds fine on Python 3.5, but fails on 2.7 and 3.4.

[What happens on Python 2.7](https://travis-ci.org/naftulikay/aws-env/jobs/216454877) when I run `bin/buildout`:

```
Installing ipython.
Getting distribution for 'ipython'.
error: Setup script exited with error in ipython setup command: Invalid environment marker: sys_platform == "win32" and python_version < "3.6"
An error occurred when trying to install /tmp/tmprLOC_8get_dist/ipython-5.3.0.tar.gz. Look above this message for any errors that were output by easy_install.
While:
  Installing ipython.
  Getting distribution for 'ipython'.
An internal error occurred due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/build/naftulikay/aws-env/eggs/zc.buildout-2.9.2-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1982, in main
    getattr(buildout, command)(args)
  File "/home/travis/build/naftulikay/aws-env/eggs/zc.buildout-2.9.2-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 668, in install
    installed_files = self[part]._call(recipe.install)
  File "/home/travis/build/naftulikay/aws-env/eggs/zc.buildout-2.9.2-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1419, in _call
    return f()
  File "/home/travis/build/naftulikay/aws-env/eggs/zc.recipe.egg-2.0.3-py2.7.egg/zc/recipe/egg/egg.py", line 126, in install
    reqs, ws = self.working_set()
  File "/home/travis/build/naftulikay/aws-env/eggs/zc.recipe.egg-2.0.3-py2.7.egg/zc/recipe/egg/egg.py", line 84, in working_set
    allow_hosts=self.allow_hosts)
  File "/home/travis/build/naftulikay/aws-env/eggs/zc.buildout-2.9.2-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 913, in install
    return installer.install(specs, working_set)
  File "/home/travis/build/naftulikay/aws-env/eggs/zc.buildout-2.9.2-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 665, in install
    for dist in self._get_dist(requirement, ws):
  File "/home/travis/build/naftulikay/aws-env/eggs/zc.buildout-2.9.2-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 563, in _get_dist
    dists = [_move_to_eggs_dir_and_compile(dist, self._dest)]
  File "/home/travis/build/naftulikay/aws-env/eggs/zc.buildout-2.9.2-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 1699, in _move_to_eggs_dir_and_compile
    [tmp_loc] = glob.glob(os.path.join(tmp_dest, '*'))
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

[What happens on Python 3.4](https://travis-ci.org/naftulikay/aws-env/jobs/216454879) when I run `bin/buildout`:

```
Installing ipython.
Getting distribution for 'ipython'.
error: Setup script exited with error in ipython setup command: Invalid environment marker: python_version >= "3.4"
An error occurred when trying to install /tmp/tmpos_bscj8get_dist/ipython-5.3.0.tar.gz. Look above this message for any errors that were output by easy_install.
While:
  Installing ipython.
  Getting distribution for 'ipython'.
An internal error occurred due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/build/naftulikay/aws-env/eggs/zc.buildout-2.9.2-py3.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1982, in main
    getattr(buildout, command)(args)
  File "/home/travis/build/naftulikay/aws-env/eggs/zc.buildout-2.9.2-py3.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 668, in install
    installed_files = self[part]._call(recipe.install)
  File "/home/travis/build/naftulikay/aws-env/eggs/zc.buildout-2.9.2-py3.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1419, in _call
    return f()
  File "/home/travis/build/naftulikay/aws-env/eggs/zc.recipe.egg-2.0.3-py3.4.egg/zc/recipe/egg/egg.py", line 126, in install
    reqs, ws = self.working_set()
  File "/home/travis/build/naftulikay/aws-env/eggs/zc.recipe.egg-2.0.3-py3.4.egg/zc/recipe/egg/egg.py", line 84, in working_set
    allow_hosts=self.allow_hosts)
  File "/home/travis/build/naftulikay/aws-env/eggs/zc.buildout-2.9.2-py3.4.egg/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 913, in install
    return installer.install(specs, working_set)
  File "/home/travis/build/naftulikay/aws-env/eggs/zc.buildout-2.9.2-py3.4.egg/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 665, in install
    for dist in self._get_dist(requirement, ws):
  File "/home/travis/build/naftulikay/aws-env/eggs/zc.buildout-2.9.2-py3.4.egg/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 563, in _get_dist
    dists = [_move_to_eggs_dir_and_compile(dist, self._dest)]
  File "/home/travis/build/naftulikay/aws-env/eggs/zc.buildout-2.9.2-py3.4.egg/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 1699, in _move_to_eggs_dir_and_compile
    [tmp_loc] = glob.glob(os.path.join(tmp_dest, '*'))
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

#### Local Development

On CentOS 7 with Python 2.7.5, it fails in the following fashion:

```
[vagrant@devel vagrant]$ python --version
Python 2.7.5
[vagrant@devel vagrant]$ python bootstrap.py
ez_setup.py is deprecated and when using it setuptools will be pinned to 33.1.1 since it's the last version that supports setuptools self upgrade/installation, check https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/581 for more info; use pip to install setuptools
Downloading https://pypi.io/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-33.1.1.zip
Extracting in /tmp/tmpftyX3t
Now working in /tmp/tmpftyX3t/setuptools-33.1.1
Building a Setuptools egg in /tmp/bootstrap-nc0bVK
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'setuptools/_vendor'
/tmp/bootstrap-nc0bVK/setuptools-33.1.1-py2.7.egg
warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'doc'
Creating directory '/vagrant/develop-eggs'.
Generated script '/vagrant/bin/buildout'.
[vagrant@devel vagrant]$ bin/buildout
Upgraded:
  setuptools version 34.3.3;
restarting.
Generated script '/vagrant/bin/buildout'.
Version and requirements information containing setuptools:
  Base installation request: 'zc.buildout', 'setuptools'
  Requirement of zc.buildout>=2.9.2: setuptools>=8.0
While:
  Installing.
  Checking for upgrades.
Error: There is a version conflict.
We already have: setuptools 0.9.8
but zc.buildout 2.9.2 requires 'setuptools>=8.0'.
```

On CentOS 7 with Python 3.4, I encounter no issues whatsoever.

### Matrix

#### Travis

- Python 2.7 (fail)
- Python 3.4 (fail)
- Python 3.5 (success)

#### Local

- Python 2.7.5 (fail)
- Python 3.4.5 (success)

---

Is there an issue with my buildout configuration? Is there a way for me to configure Travis to skip a given section during `bin/buildout` execution?

Answer (score 0):

I've run across similar issue while running from PyCharms' tools. I had script under: `/home/gonczor/Projects/STX/presence-analyzer/presence-analyzer-wgonczaronek/bin/buildout`, python 2.7.12 in venv and I had to change working directory from `/home/gonczor/Projects/STX/presence-analyzer/presence-analyzer-wgonczaronek/` to `/home/gonczor/Projects/STX/presence-analyzer/presence-analyzer-wgonczaronek` (so to remove trailing slash). I'm on Linux Mint 18 with 4.4 kernel).